# Excel SUMIF formula for cells that fall in column has "Total" and row has "Commissionable" and and row has Non-Commissionable

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs, intersect

[image]

I'm looking for some help in writing a SUMIF formula or a better alternative. The idea is the Grand Total in cell I20 will automatically

sum up cells that intersect rows with Non-Commissionable in it and columns with Total in it

and

sum up cells that intersect rows with Commissionable in it and columns with Total in it

The use case for this formula is important bc the position of rows or columns can and do change

---

Continuation Question to below commented solution

[image: =SUMIFS(XLOOKUP("Total",C4:I4,C5:I18), B5:B18, "*Commissionable")]

With this application, can I please get an understanding of why this is not applicable or not catching beyond the first match.

[image]

Comment: `=SUMIF($B$5:$B18,"Non-Commissionable",I$5:I8)` maybe? What causes the changes in columns/rows?

Comment: For rows and columns in the event that additional line items need to be added or removed. Use case is each WO we get may or may not include additional info that needs to be calculated for whatever reason. For example one WO may have a commission and no non-commission.....or one WO may have a non-commission commission and no commissionable.....Total may be in column K on one WO or maybe column L in another.

Comment: So =SUMIF($B$5:$B18,"Non-Commissionable",I$5:I8), this would seeming address looking for commission or non-commission, for I$5:I8, how can it be set to look across say ROW 2 to locate a cell that has the value "Total" and use that column.....If it were always ONLY me working this type of document I think I can go about knowing what to change to adjust for each deviation in column/row, I'm hoping for a cell that takes away the guesswork and that anyone who copies and pastes this formula will get the correct calculation.

Comment: Is it feasible to use Intersect Operator in excel for my use case? This is one that I have never used before.

Comment: Do you have MS365? Do you have many `Total` columns? Which of the following parameters will you use: the range (obviously), the name of the lookup column (`Description`), the (wildcard) lookup value (`commission*`), and the name of the total columns (`Total`)?

Comment: Yes I do have 365. I have 1 (one) "Total" Column. Lets say the range is B4:L35. Look for the wildcard name in any column that contains "Total", Look for the wildcard name in any row that contains "commissionable" AND Look for the wildcard name in any column that contains "non-commissionable". Sum up and insert value 1 cell to the right of the cell titled "Grand Total" (This step fully optional, but would be nice if possible)

Comment: The formula will be located in the cell next to `Grand Total` so you cannot achieve the last step with an Excel formula. It can be done using VBA. if that's an option, add (select) the `vba` tag at the bottom of your post. Also, add the details from the comments to your post so it becomes clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Since it looks like you have Office 365, try this simplified formula:

```
=SUMIFS(XLOOKUP("Total", C4:I4, C5:I18), B5:B18, "*Commissionable")
```

The XLOOKUP function will return the *range* of the first column found where the column header is *equal to* `"Total"`.

The SUMIFS function will then sum anything in the Total column, where the value in the Description column *ends with* "Commissionable" (`"*Commissionable"`), which will include both "Commissionable" and "Non-Commissionable".

[image: sumifs_xlookup.jpg]

**(2)** The XLOOKUP function can also perform a wildcard character search to find the column header that *ends with* "Total" (`"*Total"`) or *contains* "Total" (`"*Total*"`). To do this, you must set the optional *[match_mode]* parameter to 2 (Wildcard character match):

```
=SUMIFS(XLOOKUP("*Total*", C4:I4, C5:I18,, 2), B5:B18, "*Commissionable")
```

This method will successfully find "Total" within column headers labelled "Total Sales", "Subtotal" or "Grand Total", for example, but it will still ONLY return the FIRST match found.

**(3)** If your data set has TWO "Total" columns, and you want to include BOTH in the Grand Total, you could add a second SUMIFS/XLOOKUP combo with the optional *[search_mode]* parameter set to -1 (Search last-to-first):

```
=SUMIFS(XLOOKUP("Total", C4:I4, C5:I18), B5:B18, "*Commissionable")
   +SUMIFS(XLOOKUP("Total", C4:I4, C5:I18,,, -1), B5:B18, "*Commissionable")
```

The first XLOOKUP will find the first "Total" column searching from *left-to-right*, and the second XLOOKUP will find the first "Total" column searching from *right-to-left*. NOTE: this method ONLY works with TWO "Total" columns.

**(4)** If you need to return multiple matches both vertically and horizontally (rows and columns), you could use either the SUMPRODUCT function, or SUM with nested FILTER functions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C5:I18 * ((B5:B18="Commissionable")+(B5:B18="Non-Commissionable")) * (C4:I4="Total"))
```

**OR**

```
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C5:I18, (B5:B18="Commissionable")+(B5:B18="Non-Commissionable")), C4:I4="Total"))
```

Both of these methods are virtually identical in their logic, and neither one will accept wildcard characters. Multiple conditions using AND logic are multiplied together (*) and multiple conditions using OR logic are added together (+). In plain English, the above SUMPRODUCT formula can be read as:

> Sum all cells in range C5:I18 where the values in range B5:B18 are equal to "Commissionable" OR "Non-Commissionable", AND the values in range C4:I4 are equal to "Total".

**(5)** BONUS method to use wildcard characters with the FILTER function, by leveraging COUNTIF with the new BYROW function:

```
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C5:I18, BYROW(B5:B18, LAMBDA(r, COUNTIF(r, "*Commissionable")))), C4:I4="Total"))
```

The inner FILTER function returns the rows from range C5:I18 where the *include* conditions are met. In this case, the BYROW function loops through range B5:B18, row by row, and returns either 0 (FALSE) or 1 (TRUE) if the value in each row *ends with* "Commissionable". The resulting filtered rows are then filtered again by the outer FILTER function, this time returning the columns where the values in range C4:I4 are *equal to* "Total". The final results are then summed up by the SUM function.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this worked great. This has been very educational for me, didn't even know that XLOOKUP was an applicable function. Though for further clarification, this is only applicable to 365?

Comment: With this application, can I please get an understanding of why this is not applicable or not catching beyond the first match.

updated a pic to my original post

Comment: XLOOKUP is a relatively new function, which is only available in Excel for MS365, Excel 2021, and Excel for the web. XLOOKUP stops when it finds the first match and returns the corresponding ***range*** (can be a single cell, row or column). It's important to note that SUMIFS will only accept a ***range*** object, which is why XLOOKUP works in this case. Functions such as FILTER or CHOOSECOLS do not work with SUMIFS, as they return an ***array*** of values.

Comment: If you need to find multiple records that match both vertically and horizontally, it's better to use SUM with nested FILTER functions, like this: `=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C5:I18,(B5:B18="Commissionable")+(B5:B18="Non-Commissionable"),0),C4:I4="Total",0))` **NOTE:** the FILTER function does not accept wildcards, so to find the values in range B5:B18 that are either "Commissionable" OR "Non-Commissionable", you have to add both criteria together.

Comment: I highly recommend you check out Mike Girvin's YouTube channel for more information regarding these techniques. Some of his most recent videos were on exactly this topic. https://www.youtube.com/@excelisfun

Comment: I've edited my answer to include multiple solutions for different scenarios. Check it out to see which one meets your needs! ;-)

Comment: I'll def take a look at the channel. Thank you so much for the education on this topic and technique!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Like This ?

> =SUM($I$5:$I$7)+SUM($I$10:$I$17)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Locate Total Column to Sum Up Matching Rows

[image]

```
=LET(data,B2:L14,wc_com,"*commissionable*",wc_tot,"*Total*",
    d,DROP(data,1),
    tc,CHOOSECOLS(d,XMATCH(wc_tot,TAKE(data,1),2)),
REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tc)),LAMBDA(rr,r,
    rr+IFERROR(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(wc_com,
        CHOOSEROWS(d,r),2))*INDEX(tc,r),))))
```

Comment: In this particular code, how would I also integrate "non-commissionable" and "Total" sum "commissionable" and "Total" also?